# How to handle token mismatch exception when user delete the hidden token from firebug?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5.2 framework and i am maintaing and secure our code. Now i am facing one problem. Suppose there is one login form like this:-

```
<form id="userLoginForm" method="post" action="{{ url('/login') }}">{{csrf_field()}}
 <label>Email: </label>
 <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" class="input-style" />
<label>Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" class="input-style" />
<input type="submit" class="green-btn-style" value="LOGIN" />
```

Now my form will look like in firebug:- 
[image]

Now suppose i press delete button from keyboard now token is removed from our form. Now when i submit the form. it will show me Token mismatch expection. But i don't want to show that error to hacker or user.. 
I have implemented isset also but not working.
My login code:-

```
if(isset($data['email']) && isset($data['password']) && isset($data['_token']) && Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'],'password' => $data['password']])) {
 //redirect to dashboard
}
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: If you set your debug `.env` variable to `false` they will see "whoops! something went wrong"

Comment: it is already showing whoops like something went wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are handled by the file

```
app/Exceptions/Handler.php
```

in Laravel. You can catch Token Mismatch exceptions and perform desired action. A sample code would be

```
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
```

To catch only Token Mismatch exception, you can add this to **render method**

```
if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {

           return response()->view('errors.400', [], 400); // load any view of your choice
        }
```

Comment: its not going to abort(404); only blank screen comes

Comment: updated code to return error view. View must exist in Laravel resources/views folder

Comment: Now it is showing :- This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500